# I cannot see the sub content when I click {{#linkTo}} in emberJs

Tags: templates, model, ember.js

I' like to see the sub content When I click {{#linkTo}} using EmberJs
This is template file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="markets/sources">
    {{#each model }}
        <span>{{source_channel}}</span>
        <span>{{handle}}</span>
    {{/each}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="markets">
    <div class="leftside">
    {{#each model }}
        <span>{{name}}</span>
        <span>{{created}}</span>
        {{#linkTo 'markets.sources' this class="link" }}<span>go to</span>{{/linkTo}}  
    {{/each}}
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
</script>
```

This is the file define route.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("index", {path: "/"});                                                       
    this.resource('markets', {path: "/markets"}, function() {
        this.route("sources", { path: "/:markets_id" });
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('markets');
    }
});

App.MarketsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Markets.find();
    }
});

App.MarketsSourcesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Sources.find();
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return { markets_id: model.id };
    }
});
```

This is model file

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 12,
   adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Markets = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    created: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Sources = DS.Model.extend({
   source_channel: DS.attr("string"),
   handle: DS.attr("handle")
});

App.Sources.FIXTURES = [
    {id:1, markets_id:"1310", source_channel:"sc1", handle: "hn1"},
    {id:2, markets_id:"1310", source_channel:"sc2", handle: "hn2"},
    {id:3, markets_id:"1310", source_channel:"sc3", handle: "hn3"},
    {id:4, markets_id:"1512", source_channel:"sc4", handle: "hn4"},
    {id:5, markets_id:"1512", source_channel:"sc5", handle: "hn5"}
];

App.Markets.FIXTURES = [
    {id:"1310", name:"test1", created:"2012-2-3"  },
    {id:"1320", name:"test2", created:"2012-2-13"  },
    {id:"1512", name:"test3", created:"2012-2-23"  }
];
```

This is controller part

```
App.MarketsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({}); 
App.MarketsSourcesController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({});
```

In here, I can not see the result that I want._
And It display black content in right side when I click some anchor tag in left side
I think, "Sources" model is not integrated with "markets/soruces" template.
I'd like to see the correct result for sources model when I click anchor tag in leftside.

If it is possible, I'd like to see the result on jsbin or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is your `App.Markets` doesn't contain the properties `source_channel` and `handle`.

You might have expected the `model` hook of `App.MarketsSourcesRoute` be called which will get the correct model. but the `model` wouldn't have been called and what you pass via the `linkTo` helper will be the model, which in your case will be a single row in `App.Markets`. as said in [Ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/)

> A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the linkTo Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

So it'll be better to call `App.Sources.find()` in your `setupcontroller` as it is called always.

I've updated your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/igamot/5#/markets). Revert back if you have any queries.